# Return Values from Lightswitch Screen to Silverlight Control

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have waded through many examples of Silverlight controls being able to invoke methods and access data collections from a Lightswitch Screen.

I am wanting to access the ID field of the record in the edit form I'm currently viewing on my silverlight control so I can look up relevant data in another system.

I have tried implementing an interface in the Common project that returns a string and using the following in my Silverlight to access it.  The custom class is an interface called Silverlight Bridge and successfully can invoke methods on the screen, however, just can't seem to get a return value back.

```
    var objDataContext = (IContentItem)this.DataContext;
    var Screen = (Microsoft.LightSwitch.Client.IScreenObject)objDataContext.Screen;

    string myVar = "Empty";

    var SilverlightBridge = (LightSwitchApplication.UserCode.ISilverLightBridge)Screen;

    Screen.Details.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        myVar = SilverlightBridge.GetVehicleID();

    });

    MessageBox.Show(myVar) ;
```

It would seem that the myVar is never being set.

Is there example code that I could be pointed to or a solution that anyone could suggest?

Comment: Note: `Screen.Details.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` runs *asynchronously* **on a separate thread** and may not execute before the `MessageBox.Show` is called. Breakpoint the code on `myVar = ` instead and see if you get a value.

Answer (score 0):

With LightSwitch you want to simply bind to collections and then get the values, to be consumed by your Silverlight control, through the bindings.

In your case the "ID field of the record in the edit form I'm currently viewing" is a value in a collection (probably the ".SelectedItem" of a collection).

You want to bind your Silverlight control to this value.

You only want to use the pattern you decribed for initiating events by the user raising it on the Silverlight control.